# Remembering php form data to display currency all over a website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I've set up a currency conversion dropdown in a wordpress site.
The only thing missing is that every time I load another page, the currency will reset as the form selection was 'forgotten'.

Any ideas how to do this? I tried a suggested js cookie that I saw here, but it doesn't work.

This is what I got so far:

```
    <form name="myform" id ="myform" method="post">

    <select name="currency-select" id="sort" onchange="submitform();">

    <option value="" selected="selected">Currency</option>

                <option value="0">U.S Dollars (USD)</option> 
                <option value="1">Euros (EUR)</option>
                <option value="2">British Pounds (GBP)</option> `

    </select>

    </form>
```

js:

```
 function submitform()
{

document.myform.submit();

}
```

I tried using this code as recommended here but it doesn't really work out for me, I think I didn't do it the right way -

```
 <?php 
 `session_start();`
 if (isset($_POST['currency-select'])) { 
 $_SESSION['sort'] = $_POST['sort'];
 } 
 ?>
```

I added the $_SESSION to the form as well:

`<option value="0" <?php if($_SESSION['sort'] == "0") echo "selected";?>>U.S Dollars (USD)</option>`

**UPDATE**

I've made a few tests. The session seems to be saved (as I echoed it on a few pages while refreshing etc.) I guess the only problem now is related to the form itself. Even with the right session number, I can't get it to select the right option.

I've tried two methods, but both does not work:

```
    <option value="0" <?php if($_SESSION['currency-select'] == "0") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>U.S Dollars (USD)</option>
```

or

```
    <option value="0" <?php if($_SESSION['currency-select'] == "0") echo "selected";?>>U.S Dollars (USD)</option>
```

Comment: If you are using php could you not pass it through a $_SESSION variable?

Comment: I tried to use it now, but seems like I got something wrong

Comment: Have you update your select to take into account the $_SESSION variable? eg <option value="0" <?php if($_SESSION['sort'] == "0") echo " selected";>U.S Dollars (USD)</option>

Comment: Yeah, I think I tried to do that..
In addition to the code above - now the code I got is :
'<option value="0" <?php if($_SESSION['sort'] == "0") echo "selected";?>>U.S Dollars (USD)</option>'

Comment: also remove selected from your currency option

Comment: It doesn't help. Each refresh/change of page is resulting with going back to the default option field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd store the selected value in a `$_SESSION['selected_currency']` variable and the cross check and select it when the drop down is being populated with the currency list.

Assuming that the sessions are working, I will use something like below to keep the currency selected in your drop down.

```
<select name="currency">
<?php
foreach($currency as $value){
   if($value->currency_code == $_SESSION['currency']){
     echo "<option value='$value->currency_code' selected='selected'>$value->currency_name</option>";
   } else {
      echo "<option value='$value->currency_code'>$value->currency_name</option>";   
   }
}
?>
</select>
```

There could be shorter ways, I am using this for illustration purposes.

Comment: @yunowork I've tried to do that but I can't figure out exactly what is wrong with the code I got related to the $_SESSION. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is as far as I can remember wordpress did not use sessions.

Comment: You need to add session_start() at the top of the php config file.

Comment: I think I got the session part working, but now the problem is how to apply it on the form.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but you do know actually where your form is right?

Comment: sorry to sound dumber, but it is in the header, if that's what you asked for?

Comment: hahaa. Well the session_start() will need to be included in the WP config file. This is usually run first which means that your WP installation can handle $_SESSION variable anywhere. And as for your form, you would location where your form is (most probably it is inside a file in your theme's folder) and update accordingly. Assuming you have found where your form is, check the edited answer on how to make the currency selected in your drop down box.

Comment: Seems like the session_start(); in the wp-config file was really the issue! I didn't use your suggested code for the form itself, as it is already working :)

Answer (score 0):

For permanent retain of data you only have a few possibilities, the easiest to implement are $_SESSION, $_COOKIE or in a Database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that

1st is by adding a field to the `options.php` page and save your data then get back your data from the `options.php` for that you've to use `update_option('nameOfField_form','nameOfFieldDb');` and `get_option('nameOfFieldDb')`.

and 2nd option is by `jquery.ajax();` method save your data in `options.php`

you may find these links helpful codex

[get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

[update_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)